# Zabbix can change its graphs real-time rate?

Tags: graph, dashboard, zabbix

Good day, I'm confused about the real-time's graph. it minimum is 1 hour. and the graph refresh almost 30 seconds at a time , can we change it to be more real-time,just like 2 or 3 second.

And I try to rewrite the item Update interval (in sec), it's not useful, I try google and know that it means the interval the agent collects data from the OS or some other place.

So Basically, Who can tell me how to change it?  it can't support to change?

Every response will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You should go to your profile (in the upper right corner) and change "Refresh (in seconds)" field to your preferred value.

Comment: Ah, obviously! Thanks a lot.